# How to align the first visible ListView item with the LinearLayout top?

Tags: android, listview, animation

Is there a way to align the first visible ListView item (or if its visible area is lesser than half: align the second item) with the LinearLayout top right after the user release an scrolling click?

I'm trying to do this because its kind of annoying showing just a little bit of the top item.

I think that if this solution exists it'll be something like a Gallery animation, but I really can't use a gallery in this case because it has to be vertical.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following functions of the ListView :

***getFirstVisiblePosition()*** : This will give you the first visible item.

***getChildVisibleRect(View child, Rect r, Point offset)*** :
This will give you the visible rect. for that view. You can check the width & height of the view with the visible part of it. Then decide if you need to show that item or not by the following function.

***requestRectangleOnScreen(Rect rectangle, boolean immediate)*** : This will pull the view inside the listview such that it is completely visible.

May be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the **android:smoothScrollbar** property to false (by defualt it's true).

> When set to false, the list will use only the number of items in the
>   adapter and the number of items visible on screen to determine the
>   scrollbar's properties.

Additionally you can play with **android:fadingEdge** and **android:fadingEdgeLength** it might do the trick whithout much code.